# eventlistener to prevent refresh on touch mouse horizontal scroll/ back button javascript

Tags: javascript

The mouse wheel event (depending on mouse capability and configurations) of backwards refreshes the page 
The event must be disabled so that the user will not be able to move backwards or forward when these events are fired

```
document.mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    if (deltaY != 0){
    //Anything that makes vertical wheelscroll keeps normal
    }
    else
    {
    event.preventDefault();
    }
    });
```

An event which disables mouse backbutton or the touch mouse horizontal scroll towards left which works as back button

Comment: Ok, but... what's the question? Please share us your problem. Currently, it's hard to tell exactly what are you asking...

Comment: Need to write a event listener which disables mouse back button functionality or the touch mouse right hover action which makes the browser refresh or go back to previous page